# What are the security risks associated with leaking client_secret in OAuth2?

Tags: oauth2

There is an API that openly returns `client_secret` for each existing user, as long as you pass an email address.

Is that a vulnerability?

What are the risks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `client_secret` is designed, as the name might imply, to be secret.

[This article](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/) from the OAuth website illustrates this:

> The `client_secret` is a **secret known only to the application and the authorization server**. It must be sufficiently random to not be guessable, *[...]*
>
> It is critical that developers **never include their `client_secret` in public** (mobile or browser-based) apps.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

An oversimplified view is that the `client_id` is like a username, and the `client_secret` is like the password. An API that prints my password when giving it my e-mail address is...bad. Very bad.

Comment: Can you please help me understand what happens after an attacker gets his hands on someone's `client_id` and `client_secret`? Login endpoint uses username and password for authentication, so what do leaked client id and secret do?

Comment: Whatever you do with `client_secret` is your task to find out. It seems to me that your "interpretation" of OAuth has very little to do with the concept of what OAuth was supposed to be.